# Set my database file to be accessible to a particular IP

Tags: php, mysql

How is it possible to set my database file file.sql/file.db etc to be accessible only by some particular IP addresses ? What tool or methods help me do this ? Thank you/

Comment: If you're talking about remote access from a MySQL client, such as from PHP, you [define the host access for each MySQL user](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/adding-users.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a PHP script which act as a *proxy* to your database. The script returns the file content if (and only if) called from the specific IP, returns an error otherwise.

Comment: Otherwise known as an [API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface).

Comment: That's not really safe, as they can just request the file with the browser, you can of course configure apache to "deny all" and use a php file as a proxy.